# How to do c++ multithreading in a class (keep thread ref as member var)

Tags: c++, multithreading, class, stdthread

So I am trying do do some multithreading in c++, I am trying to use the `std::thread`. All examples I can find on the internet use the main method. But I want to create a thread in a class constructor, and join the thread in the destructor and then clean up the thread. I have tried several things like this:

```
.cpp:

#inlcude "iostream"
myClass::myClass()
{
    myThread= new std::thread(threadStartup, 0);
}

myClass::~myClass()
{
    myThread->join();
    delete myThread;
}

void threadStartup(int threadid) 
{
    std::cout << "Thread ID: " << threadid << std::endl;
}

.h

#pragma once
#include "thread"
class myClass 
{
public: 
    myClass();
    ~myClass();
private:
    std::thread* myThread;
};
```

This gives me the following error error: `C2065: 'threadStartup': undeclared identifier`. I have also tried to add the thread startup method to the class, but that gives me a whole lot more errors.

I cant figure this out, any help would be appreciated.

EDIT: `std::thread` has been changed to `std::thread*` like in my code.
If I move the function declaration of `threadStartup` to the top of my file I get the errors:

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   C2672   'std::invoke': no matching overloaded function found
```

And

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   C2893   Failed to specialize function template 'unknown-type std::invoke(_Callable &&,_Types &&...) noexcept(<expr>)'
```

Comment: Either you insert a prototype of `threadStartup()` before `myClass::myClass()` or simply move the whole function up.

Comment: Just tried it, gives me more errors as described in my edit :(. Thanks for your quick response though.

Comment: If you want `threadStartup` to be part of the class, make it `static`, otherwise, just fix the declaration order as mentioned by @Scheff. If you get other errors after that, update you question - they're probably unrelated to the snippet you posted though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cannot reproduce. Please, see my sample code `test-thread.cc`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>

class MyClass {
  private:
    std::thread myThread;
  public:
    MyClass();
    ~MyClass();
};

void threadStartup(int threadid)
{
  std::cout << "Thread ID: " << threadid << std::endl;
}

MyClass::MyClass():
  myThread(&threadStartup, 0)
{ }

MyClass::~MyClass()
{
  myThread.join();
}

int main()
{
  MyClass myClass;
  return 0;
}
```

Tested in cygwin64 on Windows 10 (64 bit):

```
$ g++ --version
g++ (GCC) 5.4.0

$ g++ -std=c++11 -o test-thread test-thread.cc 

$ ./test-thread
Thread ID: 0

$
```

Please, notice that I don't use `new` (as its not necessary in this case).

Comment: I got it to work now, thanks. After I moved my function up I forgot to readd a parameter I removed for testing purposes.

Answer (score 0):

C++ is parsed top down ans since your threadStartup function is declared after you use it, the compiler cannot find it. Declare threadStartup before you use it and you should be ok.